# What are glowing spots with the Mask of Truth?

Tags: zelda-majoras-mask-3d

I noticed that when wearing the Mask of Truth, certain spots in the world start glowing.

I didn't notice this until I entered the Ikana area, particularly Ikana graveyard.

What do these spots indicate?

Comment: And before someone asks, I used the Lens of Truth, but it didn't reveal anything there.

Comment: Can you interact with these spots? When do they occur (Day1? Day 2? Day 3? a combination?)

Comment: @Ben There's no action button command for them, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I never noticed that. Could they be mushroom locations? Are they in the same spots as the scents if you use the Scent mask?

Comment: @GeorgeT Good question, I'll have to try it when I get home from work.  That'll be a few hours, though.  The weird thing is that one was in the Ikana Graveyard itself inside a circle of stones, but another was under the third-night gravestone where Dampe is searching.

Answer (score 1):

Put a bomb down, they are secret grottos.

Comment: I'll have to try that.  I'm at work at the moment.  I've also been doing online gaming when not at work for the past few days instead of playing Majora's Mask (whoops?).

Comment: I'll have to try that too! It makes sense. I expected to have a "shard of agony" from the beginning and was surprised there was no clue for the secret grottos. This would explain it.

Comment: While secret grottos do show up this way, chests that appears when all enemies in a room are defeated also show up this way... that's what the one I saw in the underground grave near Dante was.  Might want to add that to your answer.